# Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. react-redux

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, redux-observable

I am new with reac-redux, I am trying to get collection from Firestore but now when firebase returns the data and I try to map the info to storage through redux-observable I get an error "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions." I guess it must be about the epic configuration, then I leave the code

```
Epic

import { getFirestore } from "redux-firestore";
import {
  GET_DOCUMENTS,
  GET_COLLECTIONS_BY_DOCUMENT,
  setStatus,
  getDocumentsSuccess,
  getDocumentsFailed
} from "../actions/dataActions";
import { switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";
import { ofType } from "redux-observable";
import { concat, of } from "rxjs";

export default function dataEpics(action$) {
  const getFS = getFirestore();
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(GET_DOCUMENTS, GET_COLLECTIONS_BY_DOCUMENT),
    switchMap(action => {
      if (action.type === GET_DOCUMENTS) {
        return concat(
          of(setStatus("pending")),
          getFS
            .collection("en")
            .get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {
              let listDocumentIds = [];
              querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                listDocumentIds.push(doc.id);
                getDocumentsSuccess(listDocumentIds);
              });
            })
            .catch(err => of(getDocumentsFailed(err)))
        );
      }
    })
  );
}
```

```
Action

export const SET_STATUS = "SET_STATUS";
export const GET_DOCUMENTS = "GET_DOCUMENTS";
export const GET_DOCUMENTS_SUCCESS = "GET_COLLECTIONS_SUCCESS";
export const GET_DOCUMENTS_FAILED = "GET_COLLECTIONS_FAILED";

export function setStatus(status) {
  return {
    type: SET_STATUS,
    payload: status
  };
}

export function getDocumentsSuccess(documents) {
  return {
    type: GET_DOCUMENTS_SUCCESS,
    payload: documents
  };
}
```

```
reducer

import {
  GET_DOCUMENTS_SUCCESS,
  GET_DOCUMENTS_FAILED,
  SET_STATUS
} from "../actions/dataActions";

const initState = {
  status: "idle", // "idle" | "logout" | "pending" | "login" | "success" | "failure";
  documents: [],
  collections: []
};

const dataReducers = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
case SET_STATUS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        status: action.payload
      };
    }
    case GET_DOCUMENTS_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        status: "success",
        documents: action.payload
      };
    }
  default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default dataReducers;
```

I think the error is in the epic, I have more code in a similar way

Thanks for help me.

Comment: You probably want to use redux-thunk, which is a middleware for async actions and allows you to dispatch actions in the right time they need to be dispatched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, the error was in the epic, I was trying to call the action inside querySnapshot, this is no possible, then I move the getDocumentsSuccess after

```
getFS
.collection(action.payload.language + "_" + "MachinesAndEquipment")
.get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
let listDocumentIds = [];
querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
     listDocumentIds.push(doc.id);
});  
 getDocumentsSuccess(listDocumentIds);
```